# DirectAdmin subdomain as normal domain

Tags: dns, vps

I'm having a problem with DirectAdmin when creating a subdomain as a normal domain with it's own public_html folder. When i add the subdomain under the Domain Administration everything works fine. But after waiting more than 24 hours the subdomain is still not accessible...

**Example**
I already created mycompany.com and now i add a new domain test.mycompany.com. The first domain works fine, but the second doesn't.

When i change my hosts file and pointing to my VPS ip address everything seems to work! And my subdomain is accessible.

Do i need to change some settings on my VPS when i create a subdomain as a normal domain under Domain Administration? On one of my other VPS it works fine, but not on this one..

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it! The problem was that i didn't add a wildcard to the DNS configuration...
*.mycompany.com

Comment: Create in your DNS-records a new A record with a wildcard.

Comment: your mean is that add a new A record by value like sub.domain.com ?